# real time communication between two scripts link by pipe

Tags: python, c++, bash, pipe, real-time

I have two script and I want to make them communicate for a interactive device. 
so I did :

```
./script1 | ./script2.py
```

My script1 was done in c++ (I have the source code) and script2 is a script I have made in python to interpret the output of script1 and write on serial port.

My problem is that after few time the all process start to slow down. I've test each script separately it work.... (without slowing down) may it come from the communication ? 
Do I have other alternative ? does it exist a way to "forced" the execution and take always the last output of script1 ?

Comment: You could have a look into [Unix sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket). Also [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) is an option for interprocess communication.

Comment: Thanks, but MPI seems to be for multiprocessor which is not my case, and if I use sockets, how could I received output of script1 without modify it ?

Comment: MPI is for communicating with multiple process*es* in a way that does not required all processes to be scheduled on the same CPU; it does not require multiple process*ors* to work.

Comment: @Dadep AFAIK you would have to modify your script in order to use sockets. Another option is to redirect the stdout of `script1` to the stdin of `script2`. For that you first start `python script2.py &` which will give you the process number. Then you can start `./script1 > /proc/<process-number>/fd/0` which is the stdin of `script2` (this requires `sudo` however). See also [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi).

Comment: @Dadep You could also perform the communication via an auxiliary file. That is you redirect the output from `script1` to a file: `./script1 > aux_file` and then you either make `script2.py` read directly from that file (from within the code) or you pipe `tail -f` to it: `tail -f aux_file | ./script2.py` (however I'm not sure if the second approach is at all different from what you've done already).

Comment: your second solution with file has the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the buffering. Try:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 python -u ./script1.py | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 python -u ./script2.py
```